# ASP.NET Core JWT access token revocation

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

I'm currently generating an access token (`SecurityToken`) and a refresh token (random string) upon user authentication, and storing them as attributes of my User entity.

```
User

 - ...
 - AccessToken
 - RefreshToken
```

They asked me to revoke the access token in some scenarios, and I thought of doing that by nulling the *AccessToken* attribute and checking it on every request to see if the sent token matches with the stored one. I think that's similar to what they call "reference tokens". What could be a correct approach with plain ASP.NET Core (without Identity Server 4)? Am I following the wrong path?

Comment: Just interested; who is 'they'? And why are you not using Idsrv4 for this kind of functionality. Are you looking to create your own kind of Idsrv4 token mechanism?

Comment: Yes, we already have that mechanism in place. Identity Server 4 is still in evaluation phase...